# Magnify the content of individual cells for users with impaired vision

Tags: excel

The task was to write a program to make the letters in a single cell very large and display them with maximum contrast for use by people with impaired vision. I wrote such a program and wish to share it here in my own answer below. Comments and suggestions for improvement are welcome, as are alternative answers submitting programs written for the same purpose.

Comment: Not to be a bother but it is clear to me you have an extensive Excel VBA knowledge and I'm just curious if you think you'll be able to help me on my recent question because I'm in quite a pinch, and kind of time sensitive. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a link to your question here, and I'll try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62366723/assign-different-colors-to-different-duplicate-values-in-a-range-excel-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below superimposes an ActiveX TextBox over a selected cell in which the cell contents is displayed in an enlarged format. The factor of enlargement can be set as can the back- and forecolors to control contrast. The user navigates from cell to cell using arrow keys, Enter, Shift-Enter, Tab and Shift-Tab, or clicks with the mouse. F2 enables in-cell editing of formulas (with enlarged display). Ctl+M deletes the TextBox in the current cell, Shift+Ctl+M ends the program by setting the enlargement to zero.

The code has two parts. Part 1, following below here, must be installed in a standard code module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const MagName   As String = "Magnus"

Sub SetMagnus()
    ' NIC 047 09 Jun 2020
    ' Use this procedure to set or modify the magnifying multiplier.
    ' Call it from the Macros button on the Developer tab
    ' or assign a keyboard shortcut to it.
    ' The multiplier can also be modified directly in the document properties.
    
    Dim Mag     As String
    
    Mag = InputBox("Enter the desired magnifying multiplier (< 1 - 8):", _
                   "Setting the MAGNUS property", "3")
    Magnum Val(Mag)
End Sub

Function Magnum(Optional ByVal Mag As Integer = -1) As Integer
    ' NIC 047 09 Jun 2020
    ' this function is a designed as a UDF to set or modify
    ' the magnifying multiplicator from the worksheet
    
    Dim Fun As Integer
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not (Mag = True) Then
            ' maximum magnification permissible = +8x
            Fun = Application.Min(Abs(Int(Mag)), 8)
            .CustomDocumentProperties(MagName) = Fun
            If Err Then .CustomDocumentProperties.Add _
                         MagName, False, _
                         msoPropertyTypeNumber, Fun
        Else
            Fun = .CustomDocumentProperties(MagName)
            Fun = Application.Min(Abs(Int(Fun)), 8)
        End If
    End With
    
    Magnum = Fun
    Err.Clear
End Function

Sub SetTbx(Target As Range)
    ' NIC 047 21 Jun 2020
    
    ' Set the constant 'ColorScheme' to one of the following values:-
    ' ============================================================
    ' 2 = White font on purple ground
    ' 1 = Black font on white ground
    ' 0 = font and background colours follow the scheme in the underlying cell
    '     (This is also the default and will be used if the constant
    '      'ColorScheme' identifies a non-existent scheme)
    Const ColorScheme As Integer = 2
    ' ============================================================
    
    Dim Tbx         As OLEObject            ' the TextBox being created
    Dim BackColor   As Long                 ' background color
    Dim FontColor   As Long                 ' font color
    Dim Mag         As Integer              ' magnification multiplier
    
    
    ' To add another colour scheme (e.g. ColorScheme 3)
    ' ============================================================
    '   Add another 'Case' to the statement below, e.g "Case 3"
    '       add the new line directly above the line "Case Else"
    '   Copy a line pair 'BackColor' and 'ForeColor' from one of the
    '       other schemes and paste or type below the new line 'Case 3'
    '   Change the colour specifications in the new scheme.
    '       You can use VB constants, numeric values of Long data
    '       type or RGB functions.
    '   That's all. The new scheme can now be specified using the
    '       constant 'ColorScheme'
    '   Save the workbook to make the option permanent.
    '       The other options will still be available for future
    '       use by changing the value assigned to the constant.
    '       There is no need to remove any option once it has been
    '       created.
    ' ============================================================
    
    '   Finding colour numbers
    ' ============================================================
    '   1. Colour any cell in aany worksheet with the colour you want.
    '   2. Select the cell.
    '   3. Switch view to the VB Editor window (Alt+F11)
    '   4. In the Immediate pane (at the bottom of the screen)
    '      type "? Selection.Interior.Color"
    '   5. The number of the cell's colour will be displayed in the
    '      Immediate pane. It can be used to define BackColor or
    '      ForeColor in a ColorScheme.
    '   Note: "? Selection.Font.Color" will show the font's colour.
    '         "? RGB(128, 0, 128)" will show the number specified
    '         by the RGB function.
    ' ============================================================
    
    Select Case ColorScheme
        Case 1
            BackColor = vbWhite             ' = 16777215
            FontColor = vbBlack             ' = 0
        Case 2
            BackColor = RGB(128, 0, 128)    ' = 548545 (purple)
            FontColor = vbWhite             ' = 16777215
        Case Else
            With Target
                BackColor = .Interior.Color
                FontColor = .Font.Color
            End With
    End Select
    
    
    Mag = Magnum
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Tbx = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(MagName)
    If Err Then
        Set Tbx = Target.Worksheet.OLEObjects _
                        .Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1", _
                             Link:=False, _
                             DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                             Left:=100, Top:=100, _
                             Width:=100, Height:=20)
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Tbx
        With .Object
            .BackColor = BackColor
            .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
            .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
            .IntegralHeight = False
            .ForeColor = FontColor
            .Font.Size = Target.Font.Size * Mag
        End With
        .Left = Target.Left
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Width = Target.Width * Mag
        .Height = (Target.Offset(1).Top - .Top) * Mag
        .Name = MagName
        .LinkedCell = Target.Address
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub

Sub KillTbx(Optional Ws As Worksheet)
    ' NIC 047 09 Jun 2020

    Dim Tbx             As OLEObject        ' TextBox
    Dim LinkedCell      As Range            ' Cell linked to Tbx
    
    If Ws Is Nothing Then Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Tbx = Ws.OLEObjects(MagName)
    If Err = 0 Then
        Set LinkedCell = Ws.Range(Tbx.LinkedCell)
        LinkedCell.Select
        Tbx.Delete
    End If
    Err.Clear
End Sub

Function KeyUpEvent(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, _
                    ByVal Shift As Integer) As Integer
    ' NIC 047 30 Jun 2020

    Dim Tbx         As OLEObject
    Dim n           As Long                 ' offset
    
    Set Tbx = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(MagName)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then                    ' Enter
        If Tbx.LinkedCell = "" Then         ' Exit edit mode
            On Error Resume Next            ' in case of formula error
            Range(Tbx.TopLeftCell.Address).Formula = Tbx.Object.Value
            Tbx.LinkedCell = Tbx.TopLeftCell.Address
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Function
        Else
            KeyCode = IIf(Shift, 38, 40)    ' act like Up/Down arrow
        End If
    End If
    
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 38, 40                         ' Up-arrow / Down-arrow
            n = IIf(KeyCode = 38, -1, 1)
            If ActiveCell.Row + n Then
                Range(Tbx.LinkedCell).Offset(n).Select
            End If
            KeyCode = 0
        Case 9                              ' tab
            n = IIf(Shift, -1, 1)
            If ActiveCell.Column + n Then
                Range(Tbx.LinkedCell).Offset(, n).Select
            End If
            KeyCode = 0
        Case 77                             ' Ctl + M (delete Tbx once)
            KillTbx
            If Shift = 3 Then Magnum 0      ' stop Magnus
            KeyCode = 0
        Case 113                            ' F2 (enabled in-cell editing)
            With Tbx
                If .LinkedCell <> "" Then
                    .Object.Value = Range(.LinkedCell).Formula
                    .LinkedCell = ""
                End If
            End With
            KeyCode = 0
    End Select
    
    KeyUpEvent = KeyCode
End Function
```

Part 2, following here below, must be installed in the code sheet of the worksheet on which the magnification is desired. Several copies of the same code may be installed on the code sheets of several worksheets in the same workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' NIC 047 09 Jun 2020

    If Magnum Then
        SetTbx Target.Cells(1)
    Else
        KillTbx ActiveSheet
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Magnus_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                         ByVal Shift As Integer)
    ' NIC 047 09 Jun 2020
    
    KeyCode = KeyUpEvent(KeyCode, Shift)
End Sub
```

Initiate use by setting the magnifying multiplier using one of the methods described at the top of the code's Part 1. The code remains or becomes inactive while the multiplier is set to zero.